# PHP - How do I get duration from timestamp?

Tags: php, date, timestamp

So I have an array of podcast lengths in 30:13 (minutes:seconds) format that I want to first convert to a valid UNIX timestamp and second to format this timestamp into something readable like "30 mins 13s".

My convert to timestamp function looks like this:

```
public function duration($str) {
    $a = explode(':', $str);
    $v = (($a[0]*60)+$a[1]);
    return $v;
}
```

The problem comes in when I try to format this with `date('H:i:s', $v)` which produces numbers like "17:35:50" when there is no way in hell the podcast is 17 hours long. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's not how `date()` works.

Comment: That's also not how unix timestamps work :p.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams In what respect does it not work this way? Please elaborate.

Comment: @kevinbeal Unix timestamps are relative to 1 Dec 1970 0000.  So, 30 * 60 + 13 seconds past that is some random date with no particular meaning to your application.  That's why your H:i:s is giving you that result.  Apparently that many seconds after that date/time has that particular time.

Comment: That would explain how there were no google results for what I wanted to do... :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UNIX timestamps are not meant for calculating durations, they represent a specific time as seconds since the epoch (beginning of the year 1970). If you pass a very low value to functions such as `date()` that expect a timestamp, you will get a date from the early 1970's. You'll have to do the time formatting manually.

**Edit:** Note that if you lived in the GMT timezone you would get the results you expected. This is because `date()` takes into account your current timezone when calculating the dates generated from timestamps.

Answer (score 1):

Just format it to readable string.

```
$duration = '30:13';
list($min, $sec) = explode(':', $duration);
echo "{$min}mins {$sec}s"; // 30mins 13s
```

Comment: I want to have it in a format that I can display in multiple ways which is why I thought of using a timestamp. I want to store it in a db column and format it later.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job you want. Timestamps are something differnt, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timestamp

```
// $str has the format 'mm:ss'
public function duration($str) {
    list($min, $sec) = explode(':', $str);
    return $min . ' mins ' . $sec . ' sec';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Simple Regex

```
function duration($str)
{
    return preg_replace('/^([0-9]{2})\:([0-9]{2}$)/', '$1 mins $2s', $str); 
}
echo duration("30:33");
```

OUTPUT

```
30 mins 33s
```

Hope this helps you. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

you can try for hh:mm:ss

```
list($hours,$mins,$secs) = explode(':', $yourtime);
echo $hours.' hours '.$mins .'minuts'. $secs .'seconds';
```

may this work

Answer (score 1):

Unix timestamp gives you the amount of seconds passed from January 1 1970 00:00:00, but not time period.

To achieve your task I'd do:

```
$str = '30:13';

function duration($str) {

    $a = explode(':', $str);

    $hours = floor($a[0] / 60);

    $minutes = $a[0] - $hours * 60;

    $seconds = $a[1];

    $result = '';

    if($hours) {

        $result .= "$hours hours ";

    }

    if($minutes) {

        $result .= "$minutes minutes ";

    }

    return "$result$seconds seconds";

}

var_dump(duration($str));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object.

```
function getInterval($durationString) {
    $parts = explode(':', $durationString);
    $min = $parts[0];
    $sec = $parts[1];

    $interval = new DateInterval("PT{$min}M{$sec}S");
    return $interval;
}

$interval = getInterval('30:12');
echo $interval->format('%imins %ss');
```

I'm assuming you're using a duration time format with only minutes and seconds, of course you can modify the code if you need also hours.